# $_SESSION based language selection is not working properly

Tags: php, session, smarty

My website has two languages: English and Russian. These languages' database names are EN and RU.

I use an old php+smarty script. This script's default language selection codes like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    define('LANGUAGE_ID', 'EN');
} else if ($_SESSION['language'] == '')
{
    define('LANGUAGE_ID', 'EN');
}
```

When I want to see a page in Russian, I visit any page with language phrase (?language=RU) like this:

**http://www.example.com/index.php?language=RU**

But these pages doesn't load in Russian firstly. When I clicked another link or refresh the page, then page loading in Russian. After saved the cookies, then I can see the pages in Russian when first visit. But If I delete the cookies in browser, then I couldn't see in Russian when first visit.

I tried lots of combinations but I couldn't find any solution. Do you have any idea?

Thank you very much...

**Edit:**

I found some codes in main.class.php:

```
function __construct($dbh,$smartyBuild) {
    $this->dbh = $dbh;
    $this->sitevar = @$smartyBuild->FetchSiteVar();
    $this->smartybuild = @$smartyBuild;

    if($_REQUEST['language'] !='')
    {
        $_SESSION['language'] = $_REQUEST['language'];
    }
    else
    {
        $langaugeAlready = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select value from ".TABLE_PREFIX."sitevars where array_key = 'default_language_feed'"));

    if($_SESSION['language'] == '')
    {

        $_SESSION['language'] = $langaugeAlready['value'];

    }

}
if($_SESSION['language'] !='' )
{
    define('LANGUAGE_ID', $_SESSION['language']);
}
else
{
    define('LANGUAGE_ID', 'EN');
    $_SESSION['language'] = 'EN';
}

}
```

Is the problem related with these codes?

Comment: did you consider also checking the `$_GET`?

Comment: @DanielA.White It doesn't work.

Comment: Did you start the session and in all pages using sessions?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not sure but I think all pages includes this properties. These codes are a part of config.php. I don't know starting the session situation. It could be related with this because it occured when first visits with clear browser cache.

Comment: Meaning, is `session_start();` inside all those pages and before assigning any session variables?

Comment: can you post the code right from the top of the page. could be a few things not right which we'll only know from seeing all code down to that code

Comment: @Fred-ii- I couldn't find any code like `session_start();` but I found another related codes. I added them to question.

Comment: @JonathanPlackett I found another related codes. I added them to question.

Comment: `session_start();` must be inside all files when using sessions, and where session variables exist. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- I see some codes like these `if($Users->CheckSession() === false)` Maybe coder use these codes instead of `session_start();` But I'm not sure unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I say, without all the code we are guessing a bit at what the problem is but, here goes...

It seems like you're only checking the $_SESSION variable for the language and not the $_GET variable (which gets the language from the URL). Therefore the value only changes after you refresh the page.

Try this. I am assuming your intention is to show English as a default and only Russian if it is defined in the url, but once defined to keep that language until it is put in the URL again.

```
 //start a session. must be called first on all pages you want it to work on

 session_start();


 //first check if there's a new language coming from the URL

 if(isset($_GET['language']))
     {
     // if we have a new language setting from the URL, check which one and save it in the session.
     // we check it is EN or RO before saving into the session since I don't know what you're using it for later. eg part of a DB query which would be a security risk if it is anything other than EN or RO.

     if($_GET['language'] == 'EN')
           {
           $_SESSION['language'] = 'EN';
           }
     if($_GET['language'] == 'RO')
           {
           $_SESSION['language'] = 'RO';
           }

     } 


 //now check the session variable, which will have been updated above if changed     

 if(isset($_SESSION['language']))
     {
     // already have a language saved, so let's use it

     define('LANGUAGE_ID', $_SESSION['language']);

     }
 else
     {
     // no language from URL and no language saved, so default to english

     define('LANGUAGE_ID', 'EN');
     }
```

Comment: great. accept my answer then please! and yes i am. add me on linkedin if you like.